# Can I use formula based properties in HQL?

Tags: properties, hql, derived

There's an entity with few derived properties. Can I write a HQL using these derived properties?

Example: Person is an entity. Db columns are name & dob. Hibernate properties are name, dob & age(derived using formula).
Desired result: I want to fetch persons by age using hql

Comment: yes you can. But what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to fetch entities by query.